# Binance API get_symbol_ticker() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, api, binance

I get the following error when trying to get information about a coins price, using the following code.

```
ticker = client.get_symbol_ticker(stock.symbol)
```

Also, here is the stock object.

```
class Stock:
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.alreadyHave = False
        self.prices = []
        self.priceBoughtAt = 0
        self.quantityBought = 0
        self.marketClosed = False
        self.predictedPrices = []
        # self.positiveTweets = 1
        # self.negativeTweets = 0
```

Comment: Try `symbol=stock.symbol` instead, it takes `**kwargs`.  All my code dealing with Binance uses keyword arguments and works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_symbol_ticker()` takes named parameters as shown in the [docs](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html#binance.client.AsyncClient.get_symbol_ticker).

Try calling it with:

```
ticker = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=stock.symbol)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the relevant [python-binance documentation](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html?highlight=get_symbol_ticker#binance.client.Client.get_symbol_ticker), you'll see the following for that method call:

> `get_symbol_ticker(**params)`

You need to realise that `**blah_blah` requires *keyword* arguments rather than positional ones. Hence your code needs to do this instead:

```py
ticker = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=stock.symbol)
#                                 ^^^^^^^
#                          make keyword argument
```

---

That's the simple fix, now prepare to be educated :-)

The *reason* why this in necessary is that, when a Python function takes a `**kwargs` parameter (as a *lot* of stuff in the Binance API does), it automagically constructs a dictionary for you based on the keyword arguments that you haven't explicitly extracted.

And therein lies the crux, they *must* be keyword arguments. Without that, there's no way for Python to know the key to use in the dictionary.

Consider the following code, built to emulate a method call (with `self`), even though it's not necessary here:

```py
def fn(self, **kwargs):
    print(f"self='{self}', kwargs='{kwargs}'")

fn(42, x=7, y=9)
print('-----')
fn(42, 7, 9)
```

When you run this, you'll see:

```
self='42', kwargs='{'x': 7, 'y': 9}'
-----
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 6, in <module>
    fn(42, 7, 9)
TypeError: fn() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

You can see in the first (good) call that it constructs a dictionary for you based on the names and values. In the second (bad) call, there are no keyword arguments, so it assumes they're *real* parameters, hence the mismatch on argument count.

---

And be aware that there is an equivalent positional-argument variant `*args`. The name is irrelevant in both cases, only the number of asterisks is important but, like `self` (which *could* be `me`, `this`, or even `the_object_you_would_commonly_reference_with_the_perpendicular_pronoun`), it's probably best to follow convention.

The basic idea is that Python collects all the *specific* arguments provided in the call, based on the definition. It then collects the unused positional arguments into a tuple, and the unused keyword arguments into a dictionary, and provides them if the definition has requested that.

The following code illustrates this (and also shows that the names of the arguments is irrelevant):

```py
def fn(self, *pax, w, **paxkw):
    print(f"self='{self}', w='{w}', pax='{pax}', paxkw='{paxkw}'")
    print(f"pax type='{type(pax)}', paxkw type='{type(paxkw)}'")

fn(42, 7, 8, 9, 10, w=6, x=11, y=12, z=13)
```

and the output is:

```
self='42', w='6', pax='(7, 8, 9, 10)', paxkw='{'x': 11, 'y': 12, 'z': 13}'
pax type='<class 'tuple'>', paxkw type='<class 'dict'>'
```

There you can see that `w` is not part of the keyword arguments, because you *explicitly* collected it in the definition (in the same way `self` didn't become part of the tuple).

It's a very nifty way to allow more arguments to be passed than the minimum required. For an example of the tuple variant, you could provide a generic `product` function which would multiply all its inputs, regardless of how many there are:

```py
def prod(*items):
    if len(items) == 0: return None
    result = 1
    for item in items:
        result *= item
    return result

print(prod())               # None
print(prod(7))              # 7
print(prod(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))  # 120
```

An example of the dictionary variant would be to allow use of arbitrarily-named items, not known in advance:

```py
def any_fn(**items):
    print('Called any_fn:')
    for key in items:
        print(f'    [{key}] = "{items[key]}"')

any_fn()
any_fn(pi=3.14159, e=2.71828)
any_fn(pax='handsome')
```

The output of that is:

```
Called any_fn:
Called any_fn:
    [pi] = "3.14159"
    [e] = "2.71828"
Called any_fn:
    [pax] = "handsome"
```